# How to sort a list of java object by some property

Tags: java

I have a simple class

```
public class Address {
public String name;
public long mobile;
private String description;
private String address;
private boolean live;
}
```

and  List addressList. I want to sort the AddressList object by name.
Please help me out as i am new to java.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Comment: Use Collections.sort();

Comment: `public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Address > {
    @Override
    public int compare(Address o1, Address o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }
}` then sort it `Collections.sort(listAddress, new CustomComparator());`

Comment: you can create custom Comparable/Comparator class for the same.

Comment: Use this code :`Collections.sort(addressList, new Comparator<Address>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Address o1, Address o2) {
                 return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }
        });`

Comment: Thanks.. its working fine..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddressList` object can be sorted on the basis of `name` property by using `Comparator` interface.

Please refer the [link](https://www.javatpoint.com/Comparator-interface-in-collection-framework) for more about `Comparator`